# virtual inheritance from base struct

Tags: c++, struct, structure, virtual-inheritance

```
struct A {
int i;
virtual void f() { cout << i; }
A() { i = 1; }
A(int _i) : i(_i) {}
};

struct B : A {
B() : A(2) { f(); }
void f() { cout << i+10; }
};

struct C : B, virtual A {
C() : A() {}
};
```

Can you please explain why in the C structure there will be two **A::i** and why there will be two **vptr** pointers to 'virtual tables methods' for **C** structure although **A** only has virtual method ?
I know when there is virtual inheritance from a common base there will be one instance of the common base not two ,Please advise!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Without virtual**
When inheriting without `virtual`, you can imagine the memory structure to be like this:

```
class B : A {};
```

[image: Inheritance without virtual]

The variables of `A` are "inside" (just above) the variables of class `B`.

**With virtual**
When inheriting with `virtual`, `B` just has a "pointer" to `A`:

```
class B : virtual A {};
```

[image: Inheritance with virtual]

**Your example**
This means, your example looks like this:

```
class B : A
class C : B, virtual A
```

[image: Your example]

**Only one instance of `A`**
If you only want one instance of `A`, you have to use `virtual` two times:

```
class B : virtual A
class C : B, virtual A
```

[image: Only one instance of A]

## vptr's

Here is the layout of your code as it was produced by g++ (generated with `-fdump-class-hierarchy`):

```
Class C
   size=16 align=4
   base size=8 base align=4
C (0xb7193440) 0
    vptridx=0u vptr=((& C::_ZTV1C) + 12u)
  B (0xb719f078) 0
      primary-for C (0xb7193440)
    A (0xb719a428) 0
        primary-for B (0xb719f078)
  A (0xb719a460) 8 virtual
      vptridx=4u vbaseoffset=-12 vptr=((& C::_ZTV1C) + 28u)
```

I'm a bit rusty what concerns vpointers and vtables, so I'm not sure why there are exactly those v-pointers.

However, I can tell you, that your assumption that there is only one virtual method is wrong. 
Because `B` inherits from `A` and `A::f()` is virtual, the derived `B::f()` is automatically also virtual, even if you don't explicitly write this down.

**edit:**

After digging a bit, I think I remember which v-pointers are needed and which are not.
However I won't give you any guarantee about the following.
In the following, the notation `C.B.A` means the `A`-subobject in `B`, which is in `C`, to distinguish the both `A`-subobject (`C.B.A` and `C.A`).

Each subclass needs a v-pointer. However `*(C.B.A)`, `*(C.B)` and `*C` all point to the same location (namely the beginning of the class `C` which is also the beginning of `C.B` and `C.B.A`, therefore they can share one v-pointer. However a pointer to the subclass `*(C.A)` will point to a different location, therefore another vpointer is needed there. Also note that the subclass `C.B.A` won't even be accessible in your example (gcc: "warning: direct base ‘A’ inaccessible in ‘C’ due to ambiguity").

To make it a bit clearer:
If you only had the following structure

```
class B : A {};
class C : B {};
```

only one vpointer would be needed as all pointers to any subclass of `C` would point to the same location. The vpointer would only have to point to the vtable of either `A`, `B` or `C` to tell which is the run-time type of the object.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation, but what about the last part of the question how many vptr (pointers to the virtual methods tables) and where will they be located ?

Answer (score 1):

B isn't inheriting virtualy.

So you have the A struct inherited from B and another inherited virtauly.

Comment: So C will contain two A's? in that Case when I we do this:
`C* c = new C();
c->f();`
Which of f will runs ?? B::f or A::f

Comment: @nabil the compiler will probably throw an error telling you it is ambiguous